# How can an amazing photographer grow business and visibility outside of the Indian market?

Tags: business, wedding, art

One of my friend is an amazing photographer and she has done photography for multi-cultural wedding and her work gets recognized by bunch of world renowned photographers too.

She is on her own and has categorically amazing artists on her team. They pay attention to minute details to create an experience for their client. She has resources but doesn't have a grasp on running her profession as business. Getting a client who could value and afford, for the kind of photography she does is kinda niche in Indian Market, any ideas on how to get visibility outside India or make connections to grow the business?

Comment: This isn't a question you need to ask photographers. Your friend is already an accomplished photographer. This is a question you need to ask small business owners.

Answer (score 4):

> She is on her own and has categorically amazing artists on her team. They pay attention to minute details to create an experience for their client.

Which is it...**she's on her own** OR **she's got a team**?

If she already has a business and a team, then she needs to hire a marketing professional. If she is alone, then she needs to start studying how to market.

At the end of the day, running a business is a full time job. I've started a studio with two other shooters. At this point in time, only one of those shooters now owns the business. He has hired ~5 other photographers. Oh, he still shoots maybe 2 hours per day - the rest of the time is running the business.

Your friend needs to decide: does she want to shoot or does she want to grow the business? She can't do both - so hire to fill the need.

> any ideas on how to get visibility outside India or make connections to grow the business?

This question is too broad for this site. Any question that would take a book to successfully answer is considered too broad for this site.

Speaking of that...there are books on books, courses, bachelor's degrees, and masters degrees devoted to this subject alone. There's also small business support groups / marketing groups in most communities.

Growing a business is hard. You have to budget time and money to do it. It won't "just happen." Most businesses fail to do this and of those that do, most of them fail anyway. There is no silver bullet and marketing strategies constantly evolve. What worked two years ago may be defunct today. The best thing that you can do is look at your target market and put yourself in their shoes. Subscribe to brands that also target them. See how those other (non photography) brands market and glean insights from their strategies.

Also - your friend needs to do this and make these decisions. This isn't your business and you aren't hired to do this. I know you're trying to be a good friend but if you've never run a business and are simply asking basic marketing questions on the internet, then you're not qualified to play VP of Marketing. No one is as committed as the person whose dinner depends on the business. Support your friend by either investing or advising her to go get answers on her own.